# Problem with Eigenvectors when given a matrix containing approximate numbers and symbols

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to diagonalize a certain 2 x 2 matrix, but *Mathematica* refuses to find the eigenvectors. In particular, when I input

```
Eigenvectors[{{1.8741*10^7 + 1.40161*10^6 B, 2.79374*10^7}, 
              {2.79374*10^7, -3.1235*10^7 - 1.40161*10^6 B}}]
```

(B is a parameter). I receive the error

> Eigenvectors::eivec0: Unable to find all eigenvectors

and the bogus output

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
> ```

On the other hand, *Mathematica* has no problem with the eigenvalues, for some reason. Can someone help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: `Eigenvectors[{{18741000 + 1401610 B, 27937400}, {27937400, -31235000 - 1401610 B}}]`. First section of the doumentation...

Comment: @rasher Where is it written that `Power` shoudln't be used with `Eigenvectors`?

Comment: @Öskå: First item, details (at least for v9 docs): "Eigenvectors finds numerical eigenvectors if m contains approximate real or complex numbers. " - does't like mix of symbolic & inexact.

Comment: I guess I'm not good enough in English to understand that it doesn't like the mix :)

Comment: @Öskå It's a NKE (a New Kind of English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the documentation could be clearer on this point, [`Eigenvectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigenvectors.html) doesn't like to work symbolically on a matrix containing elements with approximate numbers. The solution is to [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationalize.html) the matrix.

```
data = {{1.8741*10^7 + 1.40161*10^6 B, 2.79374*10^7}, 
        {2.79374*10^7, -3.1235*10^7 - 1.40161*10^6 B}};
Eigenvectors[Rationalize[data]] // Column
```

[image: eigenvectors]