# No eigenvectors coming for a very simple* matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages, eigenvalues

I have a question regarding the same as [Problem with Eigenvectors when given a matrix containing approximate numbers and symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45500/problem-with-eigenvectors-when-given-a-matrix-containing-approximate-numbers-and)
 and
 [Why won't Mathematica obtain eigenvectors for this symmetric matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55476/why-wont-mathematica-obtain-eigenvectors-for-this-symmetric-matrix)

I saw these well written answers but I couldn't seem to get my answer from there, I don't know why.

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of this matrix:

```
mat[k_]={{-1. (1/2 E^((0. - 1.1708 I) + I k) - 1/2 E^((0. + 1.1708 I) + I k)),
   0. - 0.389418 I, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0. - 1. I}, {-0.389418, (0. - 
     1. I) (1/2 E^((0. - 1.1708 I) - I k) - 
     1/2 E^((0. + 1.1708 I) - I k)), 0}};
Eigenvectors[mat[k]];
```

> Eigenvectors::eivec0: Unable to find all eigenvectors.

Even though, the equations are cubic, I am not getting the solution.

**Version:  11.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)**

Comment: It seems to work with `Eigenvectors[mat[k], Cubics -> True]`

Comment: Thanks @nikie. Are these eigenvectors exact?

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, the eigenvectors are exact using exact algebra, but if you evaluate them using machine precision, you might get numerical errors. I.e. larger errors than using `Eigenvectors[some numerical matrix]`

Answer (score 3):

With a bit of simplification it works.

The main two steps i added are `Rationalize` to make the matrix purely symbolic, which is good if we want the result to be fully symbolic as well and `ExpToTrig`, which simplifies the expressions in general, making the `Eigenvectors` computation faster.
Notice that `//MatrixForm` is outside the `(mat=...)` `Set` call because it's just for display purposes and shouldn't be part of the `mat` expression.

```
(mat = {{-1. (1/2 E^((0. - 1.1708 I) + I k) - 1/2 E^((0. + 1.1708 I) + I k)), 0. - 0.389418 I, 0},
        {0, 0, 0. - 1. I},
        {-0.389418, (0. -  1. I) (1/2 E^((0. - 1.1708 I) - I k) - 1/2 E^((0. + 1.1708 I) - I k)), 0}
       } //Rationalize //ExpToTrig //FullSimplify) // MatrixForm

Eigenvectors[mat]//FullSimplify//MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

[image: eigenvectors]

which gives the eigenvectors in terms of `Root` objects. If you like explicit algebraic expressions, you can add the `Cubics->True` option to the call to `Eigenvectors` like @nikie suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Thies. Just the same question(sorry for repetition), are these `eigenvectors` exact, when using `Cubics -> True`?

Comment: @L.K. Yes, in both cases they are exact. The `Root[]` representation is just more compact and more general than the explicit algebraic `Cubics`, but they are both exact symbolic representations. The only inaccuracy comes from the floating point input data, e.g. `-1.1708`. If you can replace those floating point constants with symbolic expressions, that would be even better.